# Binding IBinder and LocalBinder with pyjnius

Tags: android, kivy, pyjnius

I'm trying to wrap an android API found here https://github.com/noke-inc/noke-mobile-library-android/blob/c95e45aeba686ec4c5cca932c9b47240d0ebc9cd/README.md

I think I've get everything figured out accept this line

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder rawBinder) {

    //Store reference to service
    mNokeService = ((NokeDeviceManagerService.LocalBinder) rawBinder).getService();
```

And this is the API code its accessing found here https://github.com/noke-inc/noke-mobile-library-android/blob/ddca0be5712cf36132d551af009a1b55a37ca776/nokemobilelibrary/src/main/java/com/noke/nokemobilelibrary/NokeDeviceManagerService.java

```
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
        public NokeDeviceManagerService getService(){
            return NokeDeviceManagerService.this;
        }
}
```

What I'm currently trying to do with pyjnius is this

```
NokeDeviceManagerService = autoclass('com.noke.nokemobilelibrary.NokeDeviceManagerService')
NokeDevice = autoclass('com.noke.nokemobilelibrary.NokeDevice')
NokeMobileError = autoclass('com.noke.nokemobilelibrary.NokeMobileError')
NokeServiceListener =autoclass('com.noke.nokemobilelibrary.NokeServiceListener')

class ServiceConnection(PythonJavaClass):
    __javainterfaces__ = ('android.content.ServiceConnection')
    __javacontext__ = 'app'

    @java_method('(Landroid/content/ComponentName;Landroid/os/IBinder;)V')
    def onServiceConnected(className, rawBinder):
        nokeDeviceManagerService = NokeDeviceManagerService()
        nokeService = cast(nokeDeviceManagerService.LocalBinder,rawBinder)
        mNokeService = nokeService.getService()
        #mNokeService = ((NokeDeviceManagerService.LocalBinder)rawBinder).getService()

        mNokeServiceListener = NokeServiceListener()
        mNokeService.registerNokeListener(mNokeServiceListener)

        mNokeService.startScanningForNokeDevices()
```

I'm kind of lost on what to do on this step.  There's not many examples out there for binding services together.

Inside the NokeDeviceManagerService class theres this

```
public class NokeDeviceManagerService extends Service {
   .
   .
   .
   /**
     * Class for binding service to activity
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
        public NokeDeviceManagerService getService(){
            return NokeDeviceManagerService.this;
        }
}
```

And I'm getting an error AttributeError: 'com.noke.nokemobilelibrary.NokeDeviceManagerServic' object has no attribute 'LocalBinder'

Comment: so what problems do you have with `mNokeService = ...`? is it null or something?

Comment: Right now I'm getting an error  'com.noke.nokemobilelibrary.NokeDeviceManagerServic' object has no attribute 'LocalBinder'